# downloading large file in R

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am using `read.csv` method to download a large file

```
data <- read.csv(url("http://some_url/data.csv"),sep=";",header=FALSE,nrows=number_of_row)
```

When I run it from my local, I get no problem but when I deploy it in the remote ShinyApp server

```
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
2017-09-20T11:32:12.685102+00:00 shinyapps[214798]:   URL 'http://some_url/data.csv': status was 'Transferred a partial file'
2017-09-20T11:32:12.685912+00:00 shinyapps[214798]: Warning: Error in scan: cannot read from connection
2017-09-20T11:32:12.689155+00:00 shinyapps[214798]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-09-20T11:32:12.689157+00:00 shinyapps[214798]:     56: read.table
2017-09-20T11:32:12.689159+00:00 shinyapps[214798]:     55: read.csv
2017-09-20T11:32:12.689159+00:00 shinyapps[214798]:     54: loadIncidenceData
2017-09-20T11:32:12.689160+00:00 shinyapps[214798]:     53: prepare_incidence_data [/srv/connect/apps/predictiviz/ui.R#11]
```

Someone ahas an idea ?

EDIT : following some suggestions below, here

```
URL <- "some_url"
  download.file(URL, destfile = "./data/data.csv")
  file <- file.path("data", "data.csv") 
  data <- read.csv(file,sep=";",header=FALSE,nrows=some_rows)
```

I get the exact same message error

Comment: Be more respectful and kind to the source and `download.file()` the CSV first.

Comment: @hrbrmstr  Why would `download.file()` be more respectful and kind than `read.csv()`?

Comment: Because you're downloading a local copy and then using the local copy vs hitting the server every time, and doing so inefficiently since it's being done from within R's `read.csv()`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr sorry I missed the notification of your post. Besides, I edited my post following your suggestions but I still get the exact same error